# Windows 7 front panel audio, without bloatware?

Tags: windows-7, headphones

Asus P8H67 motherboard (not sure it's very relevant, I have had this happen with other systems as well) -- I can't get the front panel 3.5mm jack to work. I know that **it works**, because I've tested it in Ubuntu. Windows 7 says they are "not plugged in", no matter what I do.

[image: Playback Devices shows headphones as not plugged in]

I know one workaround is to install some realtek bloatware and disable front panel jack detection (or something like that), but is there no other way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Realtek "bloatware" you speak of isn't really (solely) bloatware.

It is a driver needed to detect and use the front panel sockets - it also has a UI program that displays the status of the sockets and allows you to set a few other options. The program is low on resources.

You should install the driver, then if you do not want the UI, simply use MSConfig or Autoruns to stop it from starting with the machine.

Comment: What Wil said.  You HAVE to install it.  You can disable the services/tray icons.  We do this specifically with these exact Realtek chipsets on machines we ship.

Comment: +1, I agree with that (although driver != systray bloatware). However, even if I install it, is "disable front panel jack detection" the only option? It's the only one I can find, and, it's not pretty. If I leave that disabled, front panel jack detection never seems to work (I plug in headphones but nothing happens). Is it supposed to work? I could not get that to work on my previous machine either.

Comment: I use the Realtek drivers on a desktop, and a laptop, and there is almost no footprint from it. Highly recommend using them, it brings out some great sound settings.

Answer (score 1):

Download this program (HD Realtek Audio), it will fix your problem:

[Realtek High Definition Audio Codec for Windows 7 and Vista (32-bit & 64-bit) R2.47](http://www.afterdawn.com/software/drivers/sound_card_drivers/realtek_high_definition_audio_codec_windows_7_vista.cfm)